# TypeError: vision.labelDetection is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to get Google Cloud Vision API working within NodeJS using official Google documentation and keep running into the following error. I checked multiple times, have correctly installed @google-cloud/vision using npm, everything is up to date.

> TypeError: vision.labelDetection is not a function
>       at /home/pi/functions/server.js:34:12
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pi/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/home/pi/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/home/pi/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pi/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /home/pi/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/home/pi/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/home/pi/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at SendStream.error (/home/pi/functions/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
>       at emitOne (events.js:115:13)

I have been trying to get this to work for hours upon hours, and arrived at a dead end. Have tried everything I could come up with but it keeps telling me the function doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code where you call the API ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rL0jDCLp Made a little pastebin, hope this helps!

Comment: Managed to fix it, consider this post closed!